# Elasticsearch : Check if GeoPoint exists in the radius of multiple circles

Tags: elasticsearch

My requirement is to check if a partucular geoPoint falls in radius of a circle or not.
I am using geoShape : circle to store the location. My document is as below:

```
PUT location_test/doc/1
    {
        "location" : {
            "type" : "circle",
            "coordinates" : [73.7769,18.5642],
          "radius": "10mi"
        }
    }
```

and querying is as below :

```
GET location_test/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "geo_shape": {
                "location": {
                  "shape": {
                    "type": "point",
                    "coordinates": [
                      73.877097,
                      18.455303
                    ],
                    "relation": "contains"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

This query works perfectly for single circle geo shape.
However now I want to check if a particular geoPoint falls in radius of multiple circles.
Can we have our document something like :

```
{
  "location": [
    {
      "type": "circle",
      "coordinates": [
        73.7769,
        18.5642
      ],
      "radius": "10mi"
    },
    {
      "type": "circle",
      "coordinates": [
        -118.240853,
        34.052997
      ],
      "radius": "10mi"
    }
  ]
}
```

and have a query to check if a geoPoint falls in which circle.
Or is there any another way to achieve  this ?

**EDIT**
Is it a good practice to use array of geo-points to sort documents for a particular geo-point ?

```
Mapping :
    {
      "mappings": {
        "doc": {
          "properties": {
            "locationPoint": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

PUT location_test2/doc/1
{
  "locationPoint": ["34.075433, -118.307228","36.336356,-119.304597"]
}

PUT location_test2/doc/2
{
  "locationPoint": ["34.075433, -118.307228"]  
  }

GET location_test2/_search
{
  "sort": [
      {
      "_geo_distance": {
        "locationPoint": "34.075433, -118.307228",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can surely have multiple circles in one document and the search is still going to match if *any* of the circles contain your point. Collapsing the steps for brevity:

```json
PUT location_test
{"mappings":{"properties":{"location":{"type":"geo_shape","strategy":"recursive"}}}}
```

Taking in your array of circles:

```json
PUT location_test/_doc/2
{"location":[{"type":"circle","coordinates":[73.7769,18.5642],"radius":"10mi"},{"type":"circle","coordinates":[-118.240853,34.052997],"radius":"10mi"}]}
```

Same query as for a single circle.

```json
GET location_test/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must":[
        {
          "geo_shape":{
            "location":{
              "shape":{
                "type":"point",
                "coordinates":[
                  73.7769,
                  18.5642
                ],
                "relation":"contains"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

which yields our doc of interest. The counterintuitive but nice thing about this is that it **does not matter** if you provide a single object or a list of objects. ElasticSearch handles both without a mapping change.

---

Just note that your [circles](https://gist.github.com/jzzfs/26ff92aea35a1c3fe7cf7684cfa0ecd2) are on opposite sides of the globe:

[image]

If you're aware of this and querying your `locations` makes sense like this, all is fine.

---

From a performance standpoint keep in mind that circles are represented as polygons [image]

which, depending on your ES version are represented as a bunch of [triangles](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/circle-geometry-is-not-supported/171093/6).

So you may want to index circle-like polygons instead of circles to maybe speed your indexing up or even think about merging your circles in a set of polygons (a MultiPolygon) because from what it looks like, your list of circles represents
related geometries.

Comment: great, can we load map from these geo queries?

Comment: Huh? These maps were generated using TurfJS -- https://turfjs.org/docs/#circle. Cannot just plug-n-play the ES queries & responses but it's still hella convenient.

Comment: @jzzfs I have edited the question , can you please review once.

Comment: Sure -- You can sort like that. As you probably already know, more options are listed here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#geo-sorting.

Comment: thanks for this! that was some hard to find information. not sure if this is mentioned explicitly in the docs, coudn't find it.

Comment: You're welcome @choise! Yup, the official docs could be better.
Shameless plug - a whole chapter of my ebook is dedicated to geosearch in ES. I think you'll find it useful: https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/4-geo-search-clustering-19ad5756f45542069144d9c5963fc94c

Comment: you are using `circle` as a geoshape field type here. in the docs i can read `Neither GeoJSON nor WKT supports a point-radius circle type. Instead, use a circle ingest processor to approximate the circle as a polygon.` What am i missing here?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/geo-shape.html

Comment: Looks like 8.x doesn't support them directly anymore. 7.x did: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/geo-shape.html#_circle

Comment: You shoud use a (multi)polygon as advised towards the end of my answer. Which tech stack are you using to ingest docs? I'm mostly familiar w/ nodejs & python so I can only recommend geo tools for these two langs.

Comment: I'm on aws, so actually using opensearch. i'm also ingesting using nodejs. so instead of storing a circle, i should create a multiploligon using turfjs f.e. and store that?

Comment: Correct. You can use Turf's [circle](https://turfjs.org/docs/#circle) helper.

Comment: one last question if you don’t mind @Joe-ElasticsearchBook.com why a multipolygon and not a polygon? isn’t a circle a default polygon?

Comment: Yes, a circle is a polygon by default.

I wrote "(multi)polygon" to indicate that you can include multiple circles within one document entry in ES.